# How to identify spamming script

Tags: postfix, spam

I know this is an age-old question but I've not found a satisfactory answer on how to identify a spamming script on postfix.

I know I've to look at the mail logs for postfix, get the message ID and examine the header content which I've done. I don't seem to see "X-PHP-Originating-Script" line to locate the exact script. Instead I have the line X-mailer: Mailer v1.0. Is there any other way I can locate a script that's sending out emails from my local machine?

Below is the message ID

```
*** MESSAGE CONTENTS deferred/1/17A30ED943C ***
Received: from somedomain.com (localhost [127.0.0.1])
    by mymail-server.com (Postfix) with ESMTP id 17A30ED943C
    for <someuser@aol.com>; Mon, 18 Jul 2016 12:45:54 +0300 (EAT)
Date: Mon, 18 Jul 2016 09:45:54 +0000 (UTC)
From: jms <info@somedomain.com>
To: someuser@aol.com
Message-ID: <1698090211.3510965.1468835154806@somedomain.com>
Subject: FW:  Hi nolaspud
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; 
    boundary="----=_Part_3510964_1152532126.1468835154806"
X-mailer: Mailer v1.0
```

Answer (score 1):

would be faster enable the X-PHP-Originating-Script header by allowing it in php.ini file by option `mail.add_x_header = On`.

Then just check new email in mailq.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a machine that is compromised, the first step is to disconnect it from network. Then you can replace with a new secured one.

I know this is not answer you expect, but it could be very complicate to cleanup a compromised machine. The way you ask this question shows your lack of experience in dealing with security issues and the best answer is to replace the machine with a clean and secure one.

If you want to see which process was sending the email, check for running processes, check `crontab` and `at`. Check loaded modules, check if the machine has the network cards in promiscuous mode. Use `netstat -anp | grep :25` to see which processes are connecting to SMTP. You can use [Rootkit Hunter](https://rootkit.nl/projects/rootkit_hunter.html) to search for the attack traces.